# Regex word boundary not recognizing punctuation

Tags: regex, word-boundary

I have a particular regular expression:

```
#\b[a-z0-9-_%"]+\b#gi
```

I have the following test string I am applying that regex filter to:

```
abc def ghi jkl mno %%car% __car_ tall-person "thing" 20% %30%
```

However, the detected word boundaries are as follows (square brackets represent boundaries):

```
[abc] [def] [ghi] [jkl] [mno] %%[car%] [__car_] [tall-person] "[thing"] [20%] %[30%]
```

So, certain types of punctuation ("_") are recognized at both the beginning and end of the word as "word characters."  On the other hand, other types ("%" or double quotes) are ignored when they are at the beginning of the word.  Why is this?

Comment: What flavor is this? Is it [PHP](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TwxcqZK2MQeRRpm8)? It also doesn't work on [ruby](http://rubular.com/r/fOKEIG9WVQ). Can you please show the code you've used to create the last string (with `[]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In word boundary, **word** means `\w` meta character (in most regular expression engine): `[A-Za-z0-9_]`; `%`, `"` is not in that characters: match word boundary.

I think you don't need to use word boundary:

```js
// javascript example
> 'abc def ghi jkl mno %%car% __car_ tall-person "thing" 20% %30%'.match(/[a-z0-9-_%"]+/g)
["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "%%car%", "__car_", "tall-person", ""thing"", "20%", "%30%"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Just curious, is there any way to modify the characters that word boundary considers to be "word" characters?  Or is that set in stone?  I'm using the javascript implementation of regex, by the way.

Comment: @AlexZ, As far as I know, there's no such way.